# Applying conditional formatting on task status!

Tags: ms-project

I am looking to apply conditional formatting specifically on task status field. Meaning, when the task is on schedule or complete, the task bar turns green. If the task is late, the bar turns red etc.

I have the status custom field added already, I am just looking to add color to it.

I have tried adding formulas to the custom field but all in vain. I am new to MS Project 2010 and enjoying it. But this issue is taking too long for me to crack.

Comment: Hi Omar, was the answer helpful or are you still searching? If you found your own solution, it would be great if you post it here. It may help others in the future. If you are interested, you'll find a short explanation how to mark an answer as *working solution* here http://pm.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 6):

There is no conditional formatting in Project, but you can achieve what you need through custom flag fields and some bar style formatting.  In the Status field there are four possible results: Complete, On Schedule, Late, or Future.  What color bars do you want to show for each status?  I'll walk you through the process.